# How to Start ssh-agent in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, ssh, dockerfile

When entering my container, I want to log in as user `ryan` in directory `/home/ryan/cas` with the command `eval "$(ssh-agent -c)"` run. My following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest 

ENV TZ=Australia/Sydney
RUN set -ex; \
    # NOTE(Ryan): Prevent docker build hanging on timezone confirmation
    ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone; \
    apt update; \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
      sudo ca-certificates git gnupg openssh-client vim; \
    useradd -m ryan -g sudo; \
    printf "ryan ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo EDITOR="tee -a" visudo; \
    # NOTE(Ryan): Prevent sudo usage prompt appearing on startup
    touch /home/ryan/.sudo_as_admin_successful; \
    git clone https://github.com/ryan-mcclue/cas.git /home/ryan/cas; \
    chmod 777 -R /home/ryan/cas;

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]

USER ryan
WORKDIR /home/ryan/cas
CMD eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

However, running `ssh-add` I still get the `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent` which is indicative that the `ssh-agent` is not running. Manually typing `eval "$(ssh-agent -c)"` works.

Comment: A Docker container runs a single process; what is the single process this image will eventually run?  Is there a reason you need an ssh client to run the program?

Comment: @DavidMaze The container's purpose is to emulate a fresh install of an Ubuntu system. In this container I test my `setup` script, whose purpose is to configure new systems to my workspace. Part of this script is to automatically add my ssh keys. To do this requires `ssh-agent` to be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want remove your `ENTRYPOINT` statement, and then you want:

```
USER ryan
WORKDIR /home/ryan/cas
CMD ["ssh-agent", "bash", "-l"]
```

This will get you a login shell, run under the control of `ssh-agent` (so you'll have the necssary `SSH_*` environment variables and an active socket available).

---

To understand what's happening with your container, try running from the command line:

```
bash -l -c 'eval $(ssh-agent -s)'
```

What happens? The shell exits immediately, because running `ssh-agent -s` causes the agent to background itself, which looks pretty much the same as "exiting". Since you passed the `-c` flag, and the command given to `-c` has exited, the parent bash shell exits as well.